# Could it be that a P12 Certificate has restrictions regarding using it with Postman?

Tags: postman, client-certificates, p12

i have a `P12 Certificate` and want to use it for calling a `SOAP` Service via `Postman`. If I use the certificate in Browser I get access to the `URL`. But if I using it with `Postman` I am getting `403 - Forbidden` each time.

So, before I try to dive in deeper, I would like to know if there could be possible restrictions. E.g. only Browser is accepted.

Comment: Might be that you're not sending the same headers in Postman vs Browser.
If not set spefically, Postman sets it's own user agent, but you can override that.

Comment: Thank you, but the request is the same like it is needed by the API. Saw it in the Logs from Postman. User-Agent Header is disabled in Postman. If I try it with the Mozilla User-Agent the same error occurs: 403